# PHP increase mysql value with generated html button

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this table:

```
+-----+-------+
|Name |Number |
+-----+-------+
|Tom  |12     |
|Lisa |79     |
|Steve|897    | 
|John |29     |
|...  |...    |
+-----+-------+
```

I generate multiple boxes that contain a name, a number and a button:

(php)

```
$i= -200;
while($datab=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
    $i = $i + 520;
    echo "<div class='box' style='top:".$i."px'>";
    echo "<p class='text' style='top:140px;'>".$datab['Number']."</p>"; //this should be increased when the button in this div is clicked
    echo "<p class='text' style='top:240px;'>".$datab['Name']."</p>";
    echo "<button class='button' style='position:absolute; right:30px; bottom: 20px;'>Increase number!</button>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

(this will output 60 boxes: all with a name, a number and a button)

When I click a button it should increase(+1) the value of the number in the same div as the button I just clicked.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to increase *the value of the number in the same div*, then you can do this easily with jQuery:

> echo "".$datab['Number']."
>
> "; //this should be increased when the button in this div is clicked

```
$('body').on('click', 'div.box button.button', function(e) {
    var p = $(this).closest('.box').find('p.text').first();
    p.html(parseInt(p.html()) + 1);
    // Send info to server
});
```

If you also want to update the database, you can use jQuery to fetch the relevant information and submit it to a PHP handler server-side using e.g. `$.post()`.

[This is a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/zt3scgst/).

Answer (score 0):

ok something like this will work

change the P and add

like this

```
echo "<p class='text' data-customstuff="'.$datab['Number'].' "style='top:140px;'>".$datab['Number']."</p>"; //this should be increased when the button in this div is clicked
```

Then with Jquery
something like this

```
$( ".text" ).click(function() {
 var target=$(this).data( "customstuff" );
//now target have the number you want to increase or do whatever with


});
```

i did not try it but this is the whole idea and the shortest way to get to your aim